# Translate GMT date string into PST date string and format output as 'mm/dd/yyyy - hh:mi'

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, date

I have an array like this with elements

```
var getDaysArray = [
    "2021-10-28T08:00:00",
    "2021-10-27T08:00:00",
    "2021-10-31T03:00:00"
]
```

I need to get the following result **MM/DD/YYYY - HH:MM PM Pacific Time**

I was able to replace **"-"** with **"/"** using `replace`

```
for(var i = 0; i < getDaysArray.length; i++) {
  document.write(getDaysArray[i].replace("-", "/"));
}
```

But I need to get the following result

**10/28/2021 - 19:25**

Comment: So, you need to translate GMT time to PST time and format output as `'mm/dd/yyyy - hh:mi'`?

Comment: Your question is not about ordering elements of an array at all. It is about date parsing and formatting. Refer to MDN docs of JS Date object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Parse them into actual dates, and then format them as you need (+ the timezone change). -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: `.replace("-", "/")` only replaces one `-`, not all.

Comment: This is two questions: how to parse the string as GMT/UTC, and how to format it with a specific timezone. Both have been answered many, many times before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse your input strings into dates and transform [to desired locale string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) with appropriate set of options:

```js
const datesArray = [
          "2021-10-28T08:00:00",
          "2021-10-27T08:00:00",
          "2021-10-31T03:00:00"
      ],
      
      translateDateStr = dateStr => {
        const [yyyy, mm, dd, hh, mi, ss] = dateStr.split(/[-T:]/)
        const date = new Date(Date.UTC(yyyy, mm-1, dd, hh, mi, ss))
        
        return date
          .toLocaleString(
            'en-US',
            {
              timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
              hour12: false
            }
          )
          .slice(0,-3)
          .replace(', ', ' - ')
      },
      
      formattedDates = datesArray.map(translateDateStr)
      
console.log(formattedDates)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

Comment: Thank you very much please tell me how to get the am / pm format and Pacific Time for example at the end "26.10.2021 - 06:00 PM Central America Summer Time"

Comment: Language code "us-PT" is meaningless. There is no "us" language, and subtag "PT" means Portugal. So given an unsupported language, implementations will fall back to a default language. For me, the above returns a date like "27/10/2021 - 15:00". You can also use [*formatToParts*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) to get the parts and format them however you want. Also, the OP wants to parse the timestamps as UTC, not local.

Comment: @RobG: fair point regarding locale and UTC (got fixed both), thanks for pointing out `formatToParts`

Answer (score 0):

Without using an outside library like momentjs, you'll have to re-format each array element and push them into a new array.

```
let formattedDays = [];
for(i = 0; i < getDaysArray.length; i++) {
  const date = new Date(getDaysArray[i]);
  const month = date.getMonth()+1; //months go from 0-11
  const day = date.getDate();
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const hour = date.getHours();
  const minutes = date.getMinutes();

  const dateString = month+"/"+date+"/"+year+" - "+hour+":"+minutes
  formattedDays.push(dateString);
}

console.log(formattedDays);
```

Comment: The date strings have valid ISO 8601 format so you can just parse them with `new Date()` or `Date.parse()`.

Answer (score -2):

you had to use moment.js for this solution. your code might look like this code

```
var getDaysArray = [
    "2021-10-28T08:00:00",
    "2021-10-27T08:00:00",
    "2021-10-31T03:00:00"
]

getDaysArray.forEach(x=>{
    console.log(moment(Date.parse(x), 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
})
```

Comment: _"you had to use moment.js for this solution"_ - Why? What makes momentjs so special? There are other libraries out there. Also... _"We now generally consider Moment to be a legacy project in maintenance mode. It is not dead, but it is indeed done."_ ([Source](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/))

Comment: *'> ..you had to use moment.js`* to enjoy [+72kB](https://bundlephobia.com/package/moment@2.29.1) of [legacy code](https://momentjs.com/docs/) in your bundle

Comment: because it not OK to made Bricks to build a building :).

Comment: The point is your bricks are way too decrepit to be a solid foundation for your building and they come at a cost of whole new building.